# waiting for json response in angularjs factory

Tags: json, angularjs, asynchronous

I am getting closer in my quest for a JSON response. In this example, the events variable gets populated AFTER it's returned, causing a blank output. I need it to wait. I have read that a promise is the way to go... but not sure how that would work... in my console.log you can see the array but Events.all(); returns null.

```
    .factory('Events', function($http) {
         var events="";
          $http.get('http://appserver.falconinet.com/events.lasso').then(function(resp) {
            events = resp.data;
              console.log(events);
          }, function(err) {
            console.error('ERR', err);
            // err.status will contain the status code
          })
              return {
                all: function() {
                  return events;
                },
                get: function(eventId) {
                  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
                    if (events[i].id === parseInt(eventId)) {
                      return events[i];
                    }
                  }
                  return null;
                }
              }

        })
```

and here is my controller:

```
    // events

    .controller('EventsCtrl', function($scope, Events) {
        $scope.events = Events.all();
    })

    .controller('EventDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Events) {
      $scope.event = Events.get($stateParams.eventId);
    })
```

Comment: does your endpoint have capability of returning a single event when id is sent? Or are you storing all in one file?

Comment: its just one response from the server. I can make the server do whatever I want, but this works if I hard-code the event variable, but since http.get is asynchronous, it fires off in the background an doesn't finish before Events.all gets called. This is a mobile ionic application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following will return the promise created by `$http` as well as caches the loading of all events.

```
.factory('Events', function ($http, $q) {
   function loadEvents(id) {
       var promise = $http.get('http://appserver.falconinet.com/events.lasso', {cache: true});
       // return the promise 
       return promise.then(function (resp) {
           var events = resp.data;
           if (id) {
               // returns item or promise rejection
               return getEventById(id, events);
           } else {
               return events;
           }
       }).catch (function (err) {
           console.log('Events error ', err);
       });
   }

   // helper function , returns event or  promise rejection
   function getEventById(id, events) {
       for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
           if (events[i].id === parseInt(eventId)) {
               return events[i];
           }
       }
       return $q.reject('None found');
   }

   return {
       all: function () {
           return loadEvents();
       },
       get: function (eventId) {
          return loadEvents(eventId);
       }
   }

});
```

Then in controllers you need to resove your data in the promise `then` callback

```
.controller('EventsCtrl', function($scope, Events) {
     Events.all().then(function(events){
         $scope.events = events;
     });
})

.controller('EventDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Events) {

     Events.get($stateParams.eventId).then(function(event){
         $scope.event = event;
     });
})
```

Comment: this works for the /events tab.. awesome job! however, clicking on the tab, I get an error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`  also I get : `ReferenceError: eventId is not defined`

Comment: oops  I left out `return` in `get` ...fixed now

Comment: if `eventId` is not defined need to see routing config. Should make sure it exists in controller first

Comment: changed `if (events[i].id === parseInt(eventId)) {` to `if (events[i].id === parseInt(id)) {`

Comment: would make sense to make request for a single one to API also if you are going to want that path bookmarked...will save loading all of them

Answer (score -1):

As you mentioned, wrapping your actual process in a new promise is the way to go. In order to do so, the usage of this factory needs some tweaks. Lemme try to write a sample from your script, but I don't promise to get it working on the first try :)

```
.factory('Events', function($http, $q) {
  return {
    all: function() {
      var myPromise = $q.defer();

      $http.get('http://appserver.falconinet.com/events.lasso')
      .then(function(resp) {
        myPromise.resolve(resp.data);
      }, function(err) {
        myPromise.reject(err);
      });

      return myPromise.promise;
    },
    get: function(eventId) {
      var myPromise = $q.defer();

      $http.get('http://appserver.falconinet.com/events.lasso')
      .then(function(resp) {
        var events = resp.data;
        for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
          if (events[i].id === parseInt(eventId)) {
            myPromise.resolve(events[i]);
          }
        }
      }, function(err) {
        myPromise.reject(err);
      });

      return myPromise.promise;
    }
  }
});
```

Besides everything, this can be improved as you placer but I found pretty straightforward to do so after knowing how to handle promises.

Using them would be like this:

```
// Get all
Events.all().then(function(events){
  $scope.events = events;
});

// Get one
Events.get(eventId).then(function(event){
  $scope.events = event;
});
```